# SqlDataAdapter not filling data table with SQL Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Attempting to fill a data table using `SqlDataAdapter` with a `WHERE` clause but it returns nothing. The SQL command itself returns data from SSMS and removing just the `WHERE` clause in code fills data table as expected.

```
 Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
 Dim datatable As New DataTable

 Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
   cnn.Open()
   adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [MyProjectDtbl] WHERE zipcode = 22021", cnn)
   adapter.Fill(datatable)
   adapter.Dispose()
 End Using
```

Digging through the Select command EventSink, I found:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi'

Comment: Is zipcode a numeric field on the database table named _MyProjectDbtl_?

Comment: Yes, zipcode is an integer

Comment: OT, that column should NOT be a numeric type. Area codes, phone numbers and the like are not numbers that you perform mathematics on. They should be text containing numeric characters.

Comment: from a practical sense you are correct about the zipcode field, however a where clause with a with a numeric value attempting to match numeric data in a sql table doesn't return any data.

Comment: Just to check quickly, does it return anything if you use `WHERE zipcode <> 22021`?

Comment: I suspect that that exception is a red herring. Obviously it is being caught or you'd be seeing an unhandled exception. I suspect that that occurs in code that tries to cast an object as one type and, if that fails, proceeds to cast it as another type. Exceptions being thrown is perfectly legitimate and occurs in system code all the time. It's when they are not caught that you have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with parameters.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [MyProjectDtbl] WHERE zipcode = @zip", cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@zip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 22021
        cnn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count.ToString)
End Sub
```